# Guake - Windows 10 + Bash

Tags: windows-10, bash

Is there either a way to get [Guake](http://guake-project.org/) to work on Windows 10, or an alternative drop down "console host" that will host the new Win 10 Bash?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) has a Quake-style console drop-down feature that is activated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>.

[image: Quake-style option of ConEmu software]

Comment: Will this work with Win 10 Bash?

Comment: Fully supports bash!  Awesome!!

Comment: @ppittle Unfortunately ConEmu doesn't nearly have "full support" for bash. The problem is that ConEmu is primarily built to host Windows console applications, whereas Bash on Windows is happiest in a POSIX shell like mintty or xterm.

Comment: ConEmu version 170910 fully supports CMD, Powershell, git-bash, and win 10 bash (wsl) side by side. Brilliant!

Comment: you should also check [cmder](http://cmder.net/) which integrates conemu and [clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/) adding up many other useful things as well. also installing [coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) on windows might be useful than installing [tag:bash].

Comment: how to add short key to open and close **ConEmu** like `F12` in **Guake terminal**

Answer (score 7):

Better late then never, but looks like Windows Terminal 1.9 will support this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-1-9-release/

> **Quake mode**
>
> Windows Terminal now comes with quake mode! Quake mode allows you to quickly open a >new terminal instance from anywhere in Windows by typing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. The quake window >will appear on the top half of your screen and can easily be dismissed with the >same keyboard shortcut. If you want to further customize how you can summon the >terminal, check out the new features we have added for [global summon on our docs  site](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions#global-commands).

[image]

Comment: There is a pre-release out, however WSL does not work with it.

Comment: I have been able to use the Quake style summoning in Windows Terminal 1.9.1942.0, but it will only summon a CMD ("Command Prompt") session. Is there any way to make it summon a BASH shell?

Comment: unfortunately the tabs row is not displayed in Quake mode

Comment: You can switch between the terminals in the Quake mode with `ctrl + shift + tab`, open new tabs with `ctrl + shift + number`, close tabs with `ctrl + shift + w`. It supports WSL, Powershell, CMD, and even modern Git Bash (you need to enable Git Bash integration during its installation).

Comment: it opens, wunderfull, but when I press the key binding again it opens a new terinal instead of closing the one that is already open. Any ideas how to make this old feature usefull?

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering that myself and wrote a simple AutoHotkey script to emulate this behaviour. You can get it here: https://github.com/ehpc/quake-windows-bash.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Qonsole](https://github.com/joedf/Qonsole). It can show a drop down terminal just use `Cmd`.

Here is supported Features:

- Custom hotkey
- Slide up & down animation
- Enable Ctrl+v Console pasting
- Transparency options
- Configurable with cmd & console2
- Background screen dimmer
- Internal Update check, (automatic, 5 min after start up)
- Optionally Run Qonsole when Windows Starts
- More..

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Supersuer don't show the img cause my reputitions are under 10.

Comment: Latest commit for this project was on Oct 24, 2017